# In LPC1768 change keil USBHID example for bulk transfer

Tags: c#, c, arm, usb, data-transfer

I changed the keil USBHID example like http://www.keil.com/forum/21413/lpc1769-usbhid-example/ and I could send 64 bytes about each 1 ms

my changes is a little different

```
  in demo.c and demo.h
U8 InReport[64]

U8 OutReport[64]

demo.c
void GetInReport(void) {

for(amiri=0;amiri<64;amiri++)
{
InReport[amiri]=amiri;
}
}

void SetOutReport(void) {
for(amiri=0;amiri<64;amiri++)
{
OutReport[amiri]=InReport[amiri]
}
}

hiduser.c
...
GetInReport();
for(amiri2=0;amiri2<64;amiri2++)
{
EP0Buf[amiri2]=InReport[amiri2];

}
break;

...

case HID_REPORT_INPUT;
for(amiri2=0;amiri2<64;amiri2)
{
OutReport[amiri2]=EP0Buf[amiri2];
}

usbuser.c

...
if(USB_Configuration) {
GetInReport();
USB_WriteEP(HID_EP_IN, &InReport[64],sizeof(InReport));
}
...
void USB_EndPoint1 (U32 event) {
...
USB_WriteEP(HID_EP_IN, &InReport[64],sizeof(InReport));
...
}
```

and I can receive 64 byte (0 to 63) in C# by libusb

which changes needed for bulk transfer and send multiple endpoints??. I want to reach 1Mbyte/s speed, I know it's possible but I don't know which changes is needed ...
can I use Isochronous transfer and send 1000 bytes per milisecond and reach this speed?which changes is nedd for this?

I would be so thankful if someone help me

Comment: SO is no code-review site.

Comment: @olaf he's not asking for a code review.

Comment: @RussSchultz: "which changes is ne**e**d**ed** for this?" Implies a code review. As told, this is working code (didn't check, as it is incomplete and very badly formatted&indented). But feel free to pick a different close-reason.

Comment: But, the question is a bit too broad.  Yes, you can use isochronous transfer and send 1000 bytes per millisecond.  What changes are needed?   Everything is different.  go google 'isochronous example'.

Comment: @olaf  your definition of 'code review' is different than mine, then.

Comment: @RussSchultz: Probably. How do you modify foreign code without a review? (The problem here is it is working code and there is no clear error description - well there cannot, because it is working). Note that I did not recommend to post on code review. Actually, I voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @olaf    Code review is "my code works fine, I think.  did I do anything wrong?"   This was "I can get HID working, but I need more throughput.   How, pls?"  The posted code was tangential to the actual question.

Comment: my question is not a code review.... I add my changes in keil USBHID example and mentioned I reach the 64000 bytes/second ... and I don't know which other changes is need for bulk transfer and send more than 1 endpoint?this is my main question.... :)

Comment: @RussSchultz: but isochronous transfer examples are for audio data not for a integer bytes for example.... I thankful for your responses ( you and @olaf)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the USB CDC example on how to use bulk endpoints on the µC.

There will be *many* changes, especially on the PC (host) side: You now need a custom driver - I would not trust the windows CDC driver to reach 1MB/sec on a USB full speed connection - YMMV. With newer Windows version one could try to use [WCID](https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/WCID-Devices) to load the WinUSB driver. This also means that you have to rewrite the hosts application to use the WinUSB interface.

Comment: thanks Turbo .... so can't I change the keil USBHID example for this purpose? ...